# Scala , Dataframe column with a list of values, I want to create each value as new column & want to name it

Tags: scala, functional-programming, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe column given below.

```
House_No = INT
family_details = ["name" , age , "surname" , weight]
Ownership = Boolean
```

I want to create new column to the dataframe with name, age, surname & weight.

```
House_No
family_details
Ownership
name
age
surname
weight
```

Answer (score 0):

Below solution will help you:

```
     val data =  Array((2,Array("abc","23","xyz","70"),true),(3,Array("lmn","45","pqr","50"),false))

     val rdd = sc.parallelize(data)

     val df = rdd.toDF("house_no","family_details","ownership")

val res = df.select("house_no","ownership","family_details").withColumn("name", split($"family_details" (0), ",")(0)).withColumn("age", split($"family_details"(1), ",")(0)).withColumn("surmname", split($"family_details"(2), ",")(0)).withColumn("Weight", split($"family_details"(3), ",")(0)).drop("family_details")
```